# ORACLE SQL statement to call table without only customers with product views

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have tables as follows:

```
Customer(CustomerID, UserName, Email, CustomerType)
CustomerVisit(CustomerVisitID, CustomerID, VisitDateTime, VisitLength)
Product(ProductCode, ProductName, ProductDescription, QuantityInStock, UnitPrice)
ProductView(CustomerVisitID, ProductCode, AddedToBasket)
```

And I have the command as follows

```
select customerid, customervisitid,  count(customervisitid)
from customer_aqd, productview_aqd
group by customerid, customervisitid
```

Any idea how I can represent all the items viewed with the `customervisitid` and `customerid` without having repeating `customersid` as I don't want anyone who doesn't have any `productview` data.

So, just to be clear, I only want to be able to see the customers who have a `productview` in the table and see how many `customervisits` they have with their `customerid` *but only if they have a `productview` data.*

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, using proper, explicit syntax.

Comment: could you please show me which part you are referring to or better yet give an example thanks @GordonLinoff

Comment: join without explicitly declaring the fields to join will not make sense in short

Answer (score 0):

`Inner join` the `CustomerVisit_aqd` table to the `ProductView_aqd` table:

```
select cv.customerid, cv.customervisitid,  count(cv.customervisitid)
from productview_aqd p
inner join customervisit_aqd cv on cv.CustomerVisitID = p.CustomerVisitID
group by cv.customerid, cv.customervisitid
```

Comment: select customerid, customervisitid,  count(customervisitid)
from customer_aqd, productview_aqd
inner join CustomerVisit_aqd  on customervisit_aqd.CustomerVisitID = productview_aqd.CustomerVisitID
group by customerid, customervisitid

Comment: is that what you meant? im still getting errors the table names on my database are customer_aqd, customervisit_aqd, product_aqd and productView_aqd any help would be great Thanks @joshweir

Comment: I updated my answer based on your info, you might want to update your question to correct the table names in the table definitions you provided.